# Circle and Rectangle collision

Tags: processing, collision-detection

I have a program in Processing for a bouncing ball and a rectangle. I can get the collision for the sides of the rectangle correct, but I have no idea how to get the corners. This is what I have so far:

```java
int radius = 20;
float circleX, circleY;    //positions
float vx = 3, vy = 3;  //velocities    float boxW, boxH;  //bat dimensions

void setup(){
  size(400,400);
  ellipseMode(RADIUS);
  rectMode(RADIUS);
  circleX = width/4;
  circleY = height/4;
  boxW = 50;
  boxH = 20;
}

void draw(){
  background(0);

  circleX += vx;
  circleY += vy;

  //bouncing off sides
  if (circleX + radius > width || circleX < radius){ vx *= -1; }   //left and right
  if (circleY + radius > height || circleY < radius){ vy *= -1; }  //top and bottom
  if (circleY + radius > height){ 
    circleY = (height-radius)-(circleY-(height-radius)); }  //bottom correction

  //bouncing off bat
  if (circleY + radius > mouseY - boxH && circleX > mouseX - boxW && circleX < mouseX + boxW){ 
      vy *= -1; //top
  }
  if (circleX - radius < mouseX + boxW && circleY > mouseY - boxH && circleY < mouseY + boxH){ 
      vx *= -1; //right
  }
  if (circleY - radius > mouseY + boxH && circleX > mouseX - boxW && circleX < mouseX + boxW){ 
      vy *= -1; //bottom
  }
  if (circleX + radius < mouseX - boxW && circleY > mouseY - boxH && circleY < mouseY + boxH){ 
      vx *= -1; //left
  }

  if ([CORNER DETECTION???]){
    vx *= -1;
    vy *= -1;
  }

  ellipse(circleX,circleY,radius,radius);

  rect(mouseX,mouseY,boxW,boxH);
}
```

I don't know what to put in the if statement to detect the corner collisions.

Comment: You need to rethink your "impression" of the geometry.  First: It is physically impossible for a circle to hit a corner.  Second:  You don't hit a corner, you hit two sides simultaneously.  You need to rewrite your logic with the idea that you may hit more than one side simultaneously.  Just a cursory glance at your first two if statements seems to have that covered.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out?

Answer (score 7):

The problem isn't that you need to detect the corner collision. The problem is that you current collision detection doesn't move the ball to a side when a collision is detected.

Call `frameRate(5)` in your `setup()` function to better see what's going on:

[image: bad collision]

Notice that the ball intersects the top of the box, so you multiply the `vy` variable by `-1`. That causes the circle to start moving up. But the next frame, the circle is still colliding with the rectangle, because it hasn't moved up enough yet. So your code detects that collision, multiples `vy` by `-1` again, and the ball moves back down. Next frame the same thing happens, until the ball eventually stop colliding with the rectangle.

To fix this problem, when you detect a collision, you need to move the ball so that it's no longer colliding with the rectangle in the next frame.

Here is an example of how to do that for the top side:

```
if (circleY + radius > mouseY - boxH && circleX > mouseX - boxW && circleX < mouseX + boxW) { 
    vy *= -1; //top
    circleY = mouseY-boxH-radius;
}
```

[image: good collision]

You'll have to add similar logic for the other sides, but the general idea is the same: make sure that the ball will not be colliding in the next frame, otherwise it'll keep bouncing on the edge like that.

**Edit:** Taking a closer look at your collision logic, something is still off: you're only ever checking **three** sides, when you really should be checking **all four** sides.

Let's take this one for example:

```
if (circleY + radius > mouseY - boxH && circleX > mouseX - boxW && circleX < mouseX + boxW){ 
    println("top");  
    vy *= -1; //top
}
```

You're checking that the ball is below the top of the rectangle, to the right of the left of the rectangle, and to the left of the right of the rectangle. That's going to be `true` for this case:

[image: no collision]

Add a `println()` statement to each of your `if` statements (see the example in the `if` statement above) and notice what happens when the ball is below the paddle, or to the right of the paddle.

You need to refactor your logic so that you're checking all four sides, not just three. If I were you, I'd write a function that takes the **next position** of the ball and returns a `boolean` value of `true` if that position collides with the rectangle. Then you can check before moving the ball on the X and Y axis, which tells you how to bounce. Something like this:

```
  if (collides(circleX + vx, circleY)) {
    vx*=-1;
  } 
  else {
    circleX += vx;
  }
  if (collides(circleX, circleY + vy)) {
    vy*=-1;
  } 
  else {
    circleY += vy;
  }
```

This takes the place of your four separate `if` statements, and it solves your above problem as well.